# Error executing command: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity;

Tags: apache-karaf

I get the following issue from karaf:

---

### Error executing command: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=defa-database; type=karaf.feature; version="[2.1.0,2.1.0]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=defa-database)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=2.1.0)(version<=2.1.0))" [caused by: Unable to resolve defa-database/2.1.0: missing requirement [defa-database/2.1.0] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=pax-jdbc-oracle; type=karaf.feature [caused by: Unable to resolve pax-jdbc-oracle/1.0.1: missing requirement [pax-jdbc-oracle/1.0.1] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=org.ops4j.pax.jdbc.oracle; type=osgi.bundle; version="[1.0.1,1.0.1]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve org.ops4j.pax.jdbc.oracle/1.0.1: missing requirement [org.ops4j.pax.jdbc.oracle/1.0.1] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=oracle.jdbc)" [caused by: Unable to resolve wrap_file__C__Users_nxylo_.m2_repository_com_oracle_jdbc_ojdbc8_12.2.0.1.0_ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.0.jar/0.0.0: missing requirement [wrap_file__C__Users_nxylo_.m2_repository_com_oracle_jdbc_ojdbc8_12.2.0.1.0_ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.0.jar/0.0.0] osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"]]]]

I dont understand what this error means and where is the problem

I am using karaf version 4.0.10 and i run `karaf clean`
and i want to install the custom buisiness defa-database. I would like someone to explain me what this error means. I have double checked that in my maven repository i have the mentioned ojdbc8_12.2.0.1.0_ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.0.jar in the right path.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the maven java version and re-installing the project